# Is it possible to use an "if" command with a "verify text" command in Selenium IDE?

Tags: selenium-ide

After clicking a button I want to verify if certain text has showed up. If so, run some command. If not, then test for something else. Is it possible to do this by writing the result of verify text to a variable and then testing that in an if command?

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out.

```
Command              Target                    Value
----------           --------------------      -----------
store text           id=targetText             someVar

if                   ${someVar} == "blah"
 // do something
end
```